# Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in Main JAR

Tags: java, security, applet, manifest

When I want to load an Applet on the server, the browser shows:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://<my server>:9080/ram7.5.2.1/applets/lifecycle.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyMainJar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyMainJar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.isAppletTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
Ignored exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://<my server>:9080/ram7.5.2.1/applets/lifecycle.jar
```

But the problem is I have already put the attribute in the manifest file,like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: SearchApplet
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

I don't want to change the Java Security Level or put the site into the Exception site list.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
It should add the tags to the manifest file first,but also should add the tags to the  html tag.